# How to pass IMediaFile and display the media using MediaGallery in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having trouble to display images that was selected in library to display on screen. I am using MediaGallery to select up to 10 images or videos and pass it to a different page with the media that was selected. My approach is to create a new list `List<IMediaFile> mediaFiles = new List<IMediaFile>();` that stores the media file, use `foreach` method to store each media that was selected in the list, and pass it to another page `EditPostPage`. This is the code I have.

```
private async void PickFromLibrary(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var results = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(10, MediaFileType.Image, MediaFileType.Video);

            try
            {
                if (results.Files == null)
                    return;

                List<IMediaFile> mediaFiles = new List<IMediaFile>();
                foreach (var file in results.Files)
                {
                    mediaFiles.Add(file);
                }

                await Navigation.PushAsync(new EditPostPage(userId, textId, mediaFiles));
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", $"Failed selecting medias: {ex.Message}", "OK");
            }
        }
```

Then in `EditPostPage` I have this portion to initialize. And I created `InitializeAsync` method to display the selected image to the screen as `CarouselView`.

```
public EditPostPage(int userId, int textId, List<IMediaFile> mediaFiles)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
            _ = InitializeAsync(mediaFiles);
        }
private async Task InitializeAsync(List<IMediaFile> mediaFiles)
        {
            imageSources = new List<ImageSource>();
            IsImageCarouselVisible = false;

            foreach (var media in mediaFiles)
            {
                if (media.Type == MediaFileType.Image)
                {
                    using (var stream = await media.OpenReadAsync())
                    {
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                            memoryStream.Position = 0; // Reset the stream position to the beginning
                            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => memoryStream);
                            imageSources.Add(imageSource);
                        }
                    }
                    IsImageCarouselVisible = true;
                }
                else if (media.Type == MediaFileType.Video)
                {
                    // Process as a video
                    // You can access the video data from media.OpenReadAsync()
                }
            }
        }

private bool isImageCarouselVisible;
public bool IsImageCarouselVisible
        {
            get { return isImageCarouselVisible; }
            set
            {
                isImageCarouselVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsImageCarouselVisible));
            }
        }
```

Then with the processed images, this is the XAML code I have that is supposed to display the images.

```
<CarouselView x:Name="imageCarousel" IndicatorView="IndicatorView" IsVisible="{Binding IsImageCarouselVisible}" ItemsSource="{Binding imageSources}">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding}" Aspect="AspectFill" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

I read the doc about MediaGallery in GitHub and usage of `IMediaFile` and `PickAsync` method in this link but I don't know what I am doing wrong:
https://github.com/dimonovdd/Xamarin.MediaGallery

https://github.com/dimonovdd/Xamarin.MediaGallery/blob/030678ff5bea468fe1a3e4d50951e814d1fb8585/MediaGallery/MediaFile/IMediaFile.shared.cs

Comment: you have not described any specific problem you are having with this code

Comment: When a complicated piece of code doesn't work, start with a simple test. No CarouselView. No Datatemplate. No "IsVisible" property. Just xaml to display one image, whose `Source` is the first element of your list of sources.

Comment: even better, use a `Label` with hardcoded text instead of an `Image`.  That will tell you if your `ItemsSource` is working or not.

Comment: Did you try to display the image from the a stream directly? Or you can try to pass the image file with the byte array and then convert the byte array to the stream.